# Ubuntu 20.04 can't find PCL because of incorrect include directory after installing it by `sudo apt install libpcl-dev`

Tags: ubuntu, point-cloud-library

OS: Ubuntu20.04
PCL Info:

```
Package: libpcl-dev
Version: 1.10.0+dfsg-5ubuntu1
Priority: extra
Section: universe/libdevel
Source: pcl
Origin: Ubuntu
```

**I installed PCL by `sudo apt install libpcl-dev`. and used it like this:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(test)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wno-unused-parameter)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
```

**some errors occured when I build the project:**

```
CMake Error at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl/PCLConfig.cmake:62 (message):
  PCL can not be found on this machine
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl/PCLConfig.cmake:452 (pcl_report_not_found)
  CMakeLists.txt:37 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

**I'm trying to debug the cmake source code in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl/PCLConfig.cmake:418-454`, The cmake source is shown below:**

```
find_package(PkgConfig QUIET)

file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "${PCL_DIR}" PCL_DIR)
if(WIN32 AND NOT MINGW)
# PCLConfig.cmake is installed to PCL_ROOT/cmake
  get_filename_component(PCL_ROOT "${PCL_DIR}" PATH)
else()
# PCLConfig.cmake is installed to PCL_ROOT/share/pcl-x.y
  get_filename_component(PCL_ROOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../.." ABSOLUTE)
endif()

# check whether PCLConfig.cmake is found into a PCL installation or in a build tree
if(EXISTS "${PCL_ROOT}/include/pcl-${PCL_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PCL_VERSION_MINOR}/pcl/pcl_config.h")
  # Found a PCL installation
  # pcl_message("Found a PCL installation")
  set(PCL_CONF_INCLUDE_DIR "${PCL_ROOT}/include/pcl-${PCL_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PCL_VERSION_MINOR}")
  set(PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS "${PCL_ROOT}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
  if(EXISTS "${PCL_ROOT}/3rdParty")
    set(PCL_ALL_IN_ONE_INSTALLER ON)
  endif()
elseif(EXISTS "${PCL_ROOT}/include/pcl/pcl_config.h")
  # Found a non-standard (likely ANDROID) PCL installation
  # pcl_message("Found a PCL installation")
  set(PCL_CONF_INCLUDE_DIR "${PCL_ROOT}/include")
  set(PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS "${PCL_ROOT}/lib")
  if(EXISTS "${PCL_ROOT}/3rdParty")
    set(PCL_ALL_IN_ONE_INSTALLER ON)
  endif()
elseif(EXISTS "${PCL_DIR}/include/pcl/pcl_config.h")
  # Found PCLConfig.cmake in a build tree of PCL
  # pcl_message("PCL found into a build tree.")
  set(PCL_CONF_INCLUDE_DIR "${PCL_DIR}/include") # for pcl_config.h
  set(PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS "${PCL_DIR}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
  set(PCL_SOURCES_TREE "/build/pcl-gWGA5r/pcl-1.10.0+dfsg")
else()
  pcl_report_not_found("PCL can not be found on this machine")
endif()
```

**Through debugging， I found that the environment variable `PCL_ROOT` is set to `/` and `PCL_DIR` is set to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl`. So, It can't find correct PCL include directory(the correct PCL include dir is `/usr/include/pcl-1.10`) and lead to cmake error.**

**So, what's the problem with my PCL, and how can I find PCL by `find_package(PCL REQUIRED)` successfully? Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to "change the location" of something is to create a symlink. In this case, you'd do:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl/include
sudo ln -s /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl/include/pcl
```

Then you'll probably hit:

```
No such file or directory
#include <Eigen/Core>
```

Fix it in the same way:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen /usr/include/Eigen
```